# Can't boot (grub disappeared), internal hard drive not being recognized

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, mount

Up until today, I have had a dual boot installation of Windows and Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop's internal SSD. I partitioned the drive so that most of it is for my Ubuntu installation and the rest is for Windows. I've been running this setup for 2 years, and aside from having to do a reinstall of Ubuntu once, I've had zero issues.

For some reason when I started my computer this morning, I was taken straight to the boot menu, and there were no entries at all - not for Ubuntu, not for Windows.

My first thought was to do a reinstall, since I have backed up almost everything to do with my Ubuntu filesystem.

Using a USB stick that's my live boot/reinstall device, I first tried going straight to the Ubuntu Installer from GRUB. However, the options were totally different than what I'd seen before. I had no option to update, and no option to select "Something Else" (as in the fresh reinstall tutorial). At this point I knew something was up. I ran gparted and saw that my internal drive was not being recognized at all, and the usb stick was mounted in the location where my internal drive usually is (/sda)

I tried also running the installer from within a live session, same thing happened-no option to update, no option to select “something else.” Also the only type of installation available is uefi and not bios.

I have not booted into Windows since a week ago and haven’t made any changes to that environment for months.

Finally I tried doing boot-repair. I posted the results but I’m not sure what they can tell you, since my hard drive isn’t being recognized and so it doesn’t seem to appear anywhere in the log.

Then I tried running boot-repair with an external drive plugged in, one that contained a backup of my computer.

Again my actual internal hard drive didn't get recognized at all. However from the log it seems like boot-repair did look at relevant files that were in my backup. Here is a link to the second boot-repair log, with mounted external drive containing backup files: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/9g2pfxVjjR/

Full output of boot-repair, first run (only the USB stick attached): https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WB77B4mdrC/

---

**UPDATE**

---

Here is the output of boot-info, which I ran from a live Ubuntu session: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BSFkdJ8sw7/

Comment: UPDATE: I have been trying to do a portable install of Ubuntu on an external hard drive, and now I'm running into a problem where the installer hangs if I plug in the external drive after boot. I need to do this because if I boot with the external drive plugged in, then it gets loaded first as /sda, which is where my internal drive should be if I ever get things working again. Someone, anyone, please help me! I'm going crazy here!

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: Does UEFI/BIOS see internal hard drive? If not check cables & connections.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, thanks so much for responding, and for the advice about formatting and pastie--my bad! I will remember all that for the future. I'll fix fix up the original question, and link to the output of Boot-Info as soon as I'm back at my personal computer.

Comment: @oldfred, no, UEFI/BIOS does not see an internal hard drive. You're right, I really need to check under the hood, thanks for reminding me of that.